# how do I toggle between text and a table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have figured out how to toggle between text but can't find out how to toggle between text and a table. What would I need to do to change the text into a table and the table into text on a button click?

I have tried inserting html into the js function

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>

<body>
  <script>
    function home() {
      var x = document.getElementById('myid') const home = "home";
      if (x.innerHTML !== home) {
        x.innerHTML = home
      } else {
        x.innerHTML = home
      }
    }

    function percentages() {
      var x = document.getElementById('myid') const percent = "percent";
      if (x.innerHTML !==
        percent) {
        x.innerHTML = percent;
      } else {
        x.innerHTML = percent;
      }
    }
  </script>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <p><button onclick="home()">Home</button></p>
        </li>
        <li>
          <p><button onclick="percentages()">Percentages</button></p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="myid">home</div>
  </div>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>How many levels</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4+</td>
      <td><input id="4p" type="levels" placeholder="number of levels"></td>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML has some serious problems. The `<head>` element is **mandatory**. There is a space missing in your DOCTYPE declaration. The `table` misses a closing `</table>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".show-text").toggleClass("show-table");
  });
});
</script>

<style>
.show-text p{
    display: block
}
.show-text table{
    display: none
}

.show-text.show-table p{
    display: none
}
.show-text.show-table table{
    display: block
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="show-text">
        <p>any text</p>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


<button>toggle</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Js Fiddle Here https://jsfiddle.net/vsdbL614/

Comment: No reason to use jQuery here, the question is not tagged jQuery, and OP didn't ask for it. On top of that, using external code references is frowned upon on StackOverflow unless the Stacksnippet functionality is not sufficient for the code you want to present.